# How can I get my mesh has gone off screen?

Tags: javascript, graphics, position, webgl, three.js

I cannot figure out how to detect it going off screen, can anybody help? I am using WebGL and Three.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Frustum](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Frustum.js) testing, a little like this:

```
// Create a new Frustum object (for efficiency, do this only once)
var frustum = new THREE.Frustum();
// Helper matrix (for efficiency, do this only once) 
var projScreenMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

// Set the matrix from camera matrices (which are updated on each renderer.render() call)
projScreenMatrix.multiply( camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse );
// Update the frustum
frustum.setFromMatrix( projScreenMatrix );
// Test for visibility
if ( !frustum.contains( object ) ) {
    // It's off-screen!
}
```

This is copied from [WebGLRenderer sources](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/06a19706f1adac06a16c1b826438e391eec7d343/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L3640).

Comment: I get TypeError: THREE.Frustum is not a constructor when I try to run this code

Comment: I must have had an outdated three.js file, it works now thanks!