# Error: ray.intersectScene is not a function

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have been using the `sim.js` code and its objects for a simple WebGL project. When I needed to use the `frustum` class (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125415/how-can-i-get-my-mesh-has-gone-off-screen)) I had to update my `three.js`. One thing broke:

```
TypeError: ray.intersectScene is not a function                   sim.js(line 357)
     var intersects = ray.intersectScene( this.scene );
```

I checked out the source code on git, and that function does not exist in `ray.js`. How can I update this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the three.js Wiki on Migrating: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration

Removed intersectScene from `Ray`. Use `Raycaster.intersectObjects( array )` instead.

three.js r.61

Comment: thanks @West .Was trying with ray.intersectScene .Now it works after edit